# Using Flora Bluefruit LE for music controller

Tags: bluetooth

Does anyone know how I can use HID profile to control a media player remotely? For example, using remote buttons to increase, decrease or skip and other functions related to media player with HID profile. I am aiming to buy Flora Bluefruit LE for my project and use its HID profile to control my phone's music player remotely.

Comment: What is the media player that you are using? Are you sure that you need HID BLE in order to control and not some other BT/BLE profile? I can see some Bluefruit HID examples (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-flora-bluefruit-le/example-code?view=all) but they're all related to keyboard.

Comment: I want to control a mobile phone music player remotely. Do you think is it possible with the Bluefruit HID profile?